# same template coming up for two different angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two separate angular directives that I'm calling (see below markup), but **the last template is always the one that appears for both directives** in the markup section below.

As you can see, I have the **templateUrl** set differently for both directives (in the directives section below), yet the **last** one in the markup section (attachment-modal.html) is always the one that appears.

If I make the download-modal.html the last one, then that template will appear for both directives. This is also seen by placing breakpoints in each of the directives. The first directive that you have defined in the markup, never gets executed even though it gets clicked on.

Both templates have different markup in them. If I comment out one of the directives, then the template associated with that directive comes out for both directives.

After manipulating the markup, no matter what I did, **whichever directive was the latter one, is the directive that got executed.**

It seems like I can't have two directives on the same web page because only the last one defined in the markup will get executed.

I tried it in both IE & Chrome.

**What do I need to do to have the associated templates come out for each of the respective directives?**

### markup

```
<h3 class="panel-title">Check Deposit Header Information <download download-type="CK" download-id={{cdmCtrl.copiedRow.CheckDepositHeaderId}}>
</download> <attachment attachment-type="CK" attachment-id={{cdmCtrl.copiedRow.CheckDepositHeaderId}}>
</attachment> 
</h3>
```

### templates

### download template

```
<p>For Testing Purpose: Download Type: {{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadType}}</p>
<p>For Testing Purpose: ID: {{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadId}}</p>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">File Download</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" file-download download-type={{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadType}} download-id={{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadId}}>Download files</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### upload template

```
<p>For Testing Purpose: Attachment Type: {{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentType}}</p>
<p>For Testing Purpose: ID: {{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentId}}</p>

<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">File Attachment</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="file" id="inpFile" file-model="myFile" />
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" file-upload attachment-type={{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentType}} attachment-id={{attachCtrl.attributes.attachmentId}}>Upload</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### directives

```
.directive('attachment', ['$modal', function($modal) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    replace: true,
    template: '<a style="padding-right: 5px" class="pull-right" href="#" ng-click="open()"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>Attachment</a>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
      scope.open = function() {
        $modal.open({
          templateUrl: root + 'AccountingModule/modal/attachment/attachment-modal.html',
          size: 'md',
          backdrop: true,
          controller: ['attributes', function(attributes) {
            var viewModel = this;
            viewModel.attributes = attributes;
          }],
          controllerAs: 'attachCtrl',
          resolve: {
            attributes: function() {
              return attrs;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}])

.directive('download', ['$modal', function($modal) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    replace: true,
    template: '<a style="padding-right: 5px" class="pull-right" href="#" ng-click="open()"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>Download</a>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
      scope.open = function() {
        $modal.open({
          templateUrl: root + 'AccountingModule/modal/attachment/download-modal.html',
          size: 'md',
          backdrop: true,
          controller: ['attributes', function(attributes) {
            var viewModel = this;
            viewModel.attributes = attributes;
          }],
          controllerAs: 'downloadCtrl',
          resolve: {
            attributes: function() {
              return attrs;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Can you show the two templates?

Comment: I added the templates for the question...

Answer (score 0):

For the ng-click events in the directives, I needed to specify a different name for each scope opened.

For instance, openattachments & opendownloads for the scope.open functions since scope was a global variable and the last one always overwrote the first one.

```
template: '<a style="padding-right: 5px" class="pull-right" href="#" ng-click="openattachments()"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-lg" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>Attachment</a>',
```